# Custom NSWindow drawing

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, appkit

I want to draw a custom NSWindow that allows me to add subviews even on top of the top bar ( where the traffic light buttons are and the title bar ).

When I use a transparent window and use a custom view to mimic a NSWindow I need to implement so many things by myself that I thought there should be a better way of achieving this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apple has two custom window sample projects: [RoundTransparentWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html) and [FunkyOverlayWindow](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/FunkyOverlayWindow/Introduction/Intro.html) (this one is *old*, though!). Cocoa With Love has an [tutorial article](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/drawing-custom-window-on-mac-os-x.html), and be sure to read the article linked at the bottom, about custom drawing in window frames.

Comment: RoundTransparantWindow is what I do not want, I need to implement too much myself. Using [[super contentView] superview] however, I can get an NSView on top of the NSWnidow's titlebr

Comment: @Antwan: well, take a look at the [article](http://parmanoir.com/Custom_NSThemeFrame) linked from the Cocoa With Love tutorial. It's about drawing directly into the frame view (a.k.a. `[[window contentView] superview]`).

Comment: yeah did not look at the second look you posted. By the time you answered the post I found my answer in some other opensource application. I have now about roundtransparent window but it gives me the problem of implementing everything myself -> though very nice results can be achieved by doing so. Also for going through the trouble of searching for those articles I have accepted your post as the answer.

Comment: @Antwan: No need to accept the answer if it wasn't really helpful, though I certainly do appreciate it. You should post your own answer for posterity. Anyways, glad you solved it.

Answer (score 6):

```
[[[super contentView] superview] addSubview:subview];
```

Does the trick, simply give it the rgiht frame to position it.

Comment: As of 10.10 this throws a runtime warning.

Comment: @greg any more information? I have been busy with web dev and haven't really gotten a chance to play with 10.10 yet.

Answer (score 0):

@antwan Check out the discussion on github for INAppStoreWindow https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow/issues/169